# Erro na definição de Rota Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, route, laravel-8

Sei que pode ser uma pergunta de principiante, mas realmente não consigo resolver, e eu coloco o endereço no browser a rota funciona, mas quando eu chamado da `blade` não funciona.

Eu criei uma rota nova e não estou conseguindo acessar na Blade. Abaixo o código e o erro.

web.php

```
Route::get('logteste', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@getLogteste');
```

DashboardController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Validators\UserValidator;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository, UserValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    public function getLogteste(Request $request)
    {
        echo ('teste');
    }
}
```

chamada na blade

```
<span>
    <a href="{{ route('logteste') }}">link</a>
</span>
```

Erro que está apresentando

> `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException`
> `Route [logteste] not defined. (View:>C:\xampp\htdocs\innovationone\resources\views\templates\menu.blade.php)`

Comment: Experimenta `Route::get('logteste', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@getLogteste')->name('logteste');` .... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Laravel 8 mudou algumas coisas na rota, você precisa declarar ela no *use* do web.php:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
```

Neste caso a declaração ficaria

```
Route::get('/lista', [DashboardController::class, 'getLogteste'])->name('logteste');
```

Outra opção é fazer exatamente igual você fez, declarando dentro da rota o nome completo do controller, mas neste caso a rota não possui um nome a não ser que você declare ele, então apenas adicione um nome a rota para poder usar no blade:

```
Route::get('logteste', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@getLogteste')
      ->name('logteste');
```

Comment: Faltou dizer que - método `->name('logteste')` significa o que ele precisa para definir o nome da rota e com esse nome utilizar nas `urls`

Answer (score 2):

Esse problema ocorre em questão que o `route()` espera o nome da rota e você pode estar resolvendo de algumas maneiras, uma dica antes de tudo, nas rotas, no arquivo `web.php`, você pode colocar somente o nome do `controller` que também irá funcionar, e deixar teu código mais enxuto:

```
Route::get('logteste', 'DashboardController@getLogteste');`
```

mas antes, referente ao problema principal, você pode passar a `flag` `name()` com o nome da rota que desejar, por exemplo:

```
Route::get('logteste', 'DashboardController@getLogteste')->name('teste');
```

No seu `blade` ficaria assim:

```
<span>
  <a href="{{ route('teste') }}">link</a>
</span>
```

Caso não queira passar a **flag** name na rota, pode simplesmente usar o `url()` no lugar de `route()`:

```
<span>
  <a href="{{ url('logteste') }}">link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: No 8 mudou a questão do 'DashboardController@getLogteste', tem certeza que isto esta funcionando no 8?

Answer (score 1):

Existem 3 maneiras de fazer isso, já que o Laravel 8 alterou a configuração de namespaces:

1. Adicionando o $namespace novamente na configuração para que você possa continuar usando as rotas como fazia no Laravel 7.x e versões anteriores
2. Usar o namespace completo em seus arquivos de rota ao usar a sintaxe de string
3. Usar a sintaxe de ação – action syntax(recomendado)

### Adicionando a configuração do $namespace

Isso é bastante simples. Acesse o arquivo RoutesServiceProvider.php, primeiramente insira a linha a seguir no início da classe (ou retire o comentário se ela existir assim):

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

### Usando o namespace completo

Esta alteração envolve alterar todas as suas declarações de rota. Apesar de trabalhoso é simples: prefixe os nomes dos seus controladores com seus namespaces. No exemplo a seguir para uma classe ArtigosController dentro da pasta app/Http/Controllers:

```
// note como adicionamos o namespace completo antes do nome da classe
Route::get('artigos', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArtigosController@getAll');
```

### Usando a sintaxe de ação – action syntax

Esta é a alternativa mais recentemente recomendada por ser menos suscetível a erros de digitação e, em minha experiência, oferece melhor suporte ao IDE, pois informamos explicitamente ao código qual classe usar.

Portanto, ao invés de usarmos a sintaxe de string usual, podemos usar a sintaxe de ação em que especificamos a classe e o método a serem usados em uma matriz como parâmetro do método da rota sendo configurado:

```
// sintaxe de string
Route::get('artigos', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArtigosController@getAll');

// sintaxe ação. 
use App\Http\Controllers\ArtigosController;

Route::get('artigos', [ArtigosController::class, 'getAll']);
```

Para detalhes sobre estas soluções leia o artigo [Como corrigir o erro “Target class [Controller] does not exist” no Laravel](https://mazer.dev/como-corrigir-o-erro-target-class-does-not-exist-no-laravel-8/)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos consegui resolver como vcs sugeriram

```
Route::get('/lista', [DashboardController::class, 'getLogteste'])->name('logteste');
```

Comment: Não precisa responder aquilo que já foi respondido pelos amigos das resposta, é só assinalar uma das respostas como solução da sua pergunta